# Replacing values in a list of lists with dictionary values, pythonic or better way

Tags: python

I have a `dictionary` like below:

```
my_dict = {'0123': 'apple',
           '2314': 'banana',
           '5214': 'cherry'}
```

And I have a `list of lists` like below:

```
my_list = [[0021, '0123', 10],
           [0025, '0123', 12],
           [0032, '2314', 8],
           [0045, '0123', 13],
           [0060, '5214', 12], 
           [0067, '2314', 10], ...]
```

I want to replace the values in the `1th index` in lists in `my_list` with corresponding values from `my_dict`. I can achieve this with:

```
for number, fruit in my_dict.items():
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        my_list[i][1] = my_list[i][1].replace(number, fruit)
```

And my output becomes:

```
[[0021, 'apple', 10],
 [0025, 'apple', 12],
 [0032, 'banana', 8],
 [0045, 'apple', 13],
 [0060, 'cherry', 12], 
 [0067, 'banana', 10], ...]
```

But I suppose this is not a great way to do it because it continues to iterate over already replaced values. It iterates over `my_list` as much as the key number in `my_dict`. Can we do this in a better way?

Comment: Are you able to use pandas? Seems like a basic join operation

Comment: @OneCricketeer Wouldn't pandas make these operations much slower? I am trying to do this with least time possible

Comment: Many pandas operations are vectorized. Joins are a common operation, so are likely very optimized (at least compared to the loop you're doing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just loop over the list and do a look up in the dict

```
my_list = [['0021', '0123', 10],
           ['0025', '0123', 12],
           ['0032', '2314', 8],
           ['0045', '0123', 13],
           ['0060', '5214', 12],
           ['0067', '2314', 10]]
my_dict = {'0123': 'apple',
           '2314': 'banana',
           '5214': 'cherry'}

for entry in my_list:
    entry[1] = my_dict.get(entry[1])
print(my_list)
```

output

```
[['0021', 'apple', 10], ['0025', 'apple', 12], ['0032', 'banana', 8], ['0045', 'apple', 13], ['0060', 'cherry', 12], ['0067', 'banana', 10]]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely the best answer since the time it required is halved.